# WaterMarkExtender For Masked Field Not Working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

When i applied water mark Extender  on Asp.net Password TextBox Field . Its showing some **symbols not the watermark Text**.What i need to do to Show a proper Watermark Text

Answer (score 0):

From this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/984162.aspx):

> TextboxWatermarkExtender works by setting the text/style of the
>   textbox whenever it has no value and changing it when the user enters
>   the textbox.  Clearly this wouldn't work with the password field
>   because the watermark text would also be protected.  You could modify
>   it though and create a PasswordWatermarkExtender control that toggled
>   between a regular textbox with the watermark text and a password
>   textbox used for entering the value.

Comment: It would be helpful to summarise the key points here in the answer, rather than just link to an external site.

Comment: thanks to guide me , gradually  i am learning to use stackoverflow